# SQLite can't open database in Win98

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm having a problem using my code to access a database created from sqlite on a Windows 98 computer. While outputting the error message, I get a disk I/O error. I'm using sqlite version 3.6.23 in order to create the database. Here is the part of my code that calls on sqlite3 in order to access the database:

```
int sqlite3_extended_result_codes(sqlite3*, int on);
int result = sqlite3_open_v2(sqliteDatabasePath, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL);
if(result != SQLITE_OK)
{
  cout << "Error opening database file: " << sqliteDatabasePath
       << endl << "Sqlite3 Error Code: " << result
       << endl;
  cout << sqlite3_extended_errcode(database) << endl;
  throw;
}
cout << "Successfully opened database " << sqliteDatabasePath << endl;
```

I haven't found anything that would tell me otherwise why this wouldn't work in Win98, but maybe I didn't look hard enough. Any hints or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would not expect any code to run on OS older thast Windows 10 if the author do not explicitly say it support older OS. In my works. I stop to support Windows 95/98/Me about 20 years ago and never look back. By the way, usually one would only support version of Windows that Microsoft still support officially.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue and has already been discussed in SQLITE forums.

The reason being a change in "OVERLAPPED when read and write files". As per SQLITE, they do not recommend using it on older versions of windows. If you really have to use it, prefer older versions.

Run through this link, they have suggested an alternative to make sqlite working on windows 98.

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Running-on-windows-98-td66471.html